# How to prevent video tag from loading on mobile platform?

Tags: html, video

I have the following video HTML5 element, but I don't want this to load for mobile devices because of the size. I believe `display:none;` does load the video file, how can I stop that?

```
<video autoplay loop>
      <source src="Images/Comp 2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you remove the `autoplay` attribute, and start playback if, and only if, the browser doesn't identify as mobile, via JavaScript. 
That's probably both the most straightforward and portable solution.

Now, maybe CSS would also be helpful:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  media="handheld" href="mbile.css">
```

with a CSS that hides your `<video>`.

I've been, however, told, that modern Browsers on phones just ignore these; they claim that this anti-standard behaviour is useful to the user, because a smart phone of 2016 is as capable as a PC was back when the CSS media selectors were introduced, thus making people with full-HD screens on their phones visit pages that look like the WAP internet of 2000.

Comment: Wouldn't that still download the video first?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards: Not if your browser is any clever, so, no, probably not on a mobile device. Videos are generally streamed on demand, and not downloaded in their entirety first. 
now, every serious website I know doesn't use autoplay but uses JS to detect the environment, chooses a viable video quality, defines that as source for the video and then starts playing, while displaying a static image as preview for the time until that can happen.